# Get notified when a new form is shown/open

Tags: delphi, vcl

TApplication triggers the event OnModalBegin when a modal TForm is opened.

Is there a way to get notified when a non modal TForm is shown/opened the same wayt TApplication.OnModalBegin does ?

Comment: There is no centralized event for that, no.  But each `TForm` class has its own `OnShow` event, which you can use to notify the rest of your code as needed.

Comment: Make your own custom form. Have all your application forms inherit from it.  Then you can implement any functionality you want in the base class and it will be available in all of your forms.  This is generally good advice for any application you build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture some messages on `TApplicationEvents` that can help you to detect when a new form is created/showed.

Use this code on `OnMessage` event of `TApplicationEvents` component.

```
procedure TFormMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  f:TCustomForm;

  function GetFormByHandle(const AHandle:Hwnd):TCustomForm;
  var
    i:Integer;
  begin
    Result := nil;
    for i := 0 to (Screen.FormCount - 1) do
      if (Screen.Forms[i].Handle = AHandle) then
        Result := Screen.Forms[i];
  end;
begin
  if (Msg.message = WM_DWMNCRENDERINGCHANGED) then begin  // detect new form
    f := GetFormByHandle(Msg.hwnd);  // Search on Scren by handle
    if Assigned(f) then
      Memo1.Lines.Add('   Name:' + f.Name + '   - Handle: ' + IntToStr(Msg.hwnd) + '  - Classname: ' + f.ClassName);  /7 show info
  end;
end;
```

When a new form is created you can obtain his information using the Handle (come with params of message) and interrogate the `Screen` object (singleton created).

[image]

Comment: Just note that the `OnMessage` event only works for messages posted through the main UI thread's message queue, but a lot of window messages don't go through the queue. And the purpose of `WM_DWMNCRENDERINGCHANGED` is not to notify when a new window is created/shown. Personally, I would use `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()` to detect that.